# Parsing allocation and matching it with de-allocations - taking lot of time

Tags: c#, parsing, logfile

I'm trying to parse a text file which has allocation address and de-allocation address

**sample file**

```
02/01/18:09:36:48[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233272976
02/01/18:09:36:48[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233273480
02/01/18:09:36:48[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233273648
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233270456
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233270120
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233273816
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233273984
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233274152
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233269952
02/01/18:09:36:49[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233270624
02/01/18:09:36:50[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233270288
02/01/18:09:36:50[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :233274992
02/01/18:09:36:50[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195645608
02/01/18:09:36:51[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195645944
02/01/18:09:36:51[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195646616
02/01/18:09:36:51[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195646952
02/01/18:09:36:51[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195648128
02/01/18:09:36:54[INFO]::Allocation (FUNC)Get the values of Items -> Item :195638384
02/01/18:09:36:54[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :233272976
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :233270120
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :233273984
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195646112
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195648800
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195647288
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195644096
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195646448
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195644600
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195646784
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195646280
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195648632
02/01/18:09:36:55[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195648128
02/01/18:09:37:00[INFO]::Deallocation (FUNC)Delete the values of Item -> Item :195638384
```

**Here is the program i'm trying to do the parsing**

```
class ReadFromFile1
{

   static Dictionary<int, int> IndexesTobeRemoved;
   static List<string> linesList;
   static string strFileName = @"C:\LogFile.Log";

   static void Main()
   {
             linesList = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName).ToList();

             IndexesTobeRemoved = new Dictionary<int, int>();

             bool bRet = false;
            int iAllocationIndex = 0;
            do
            {
              bRet = RepeatIfMatchFound(ref iAllocationIndex);
            } while (bRet);


         foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in IndexesTobeRemoved)
         {
           linesList[item.Value] = " ";
         }
        File.WriteAllLines(strFileName, linesList.ToArray());
   }

   private static bool RepeatIfMatchFound(ref int iAllocationIndex)
   {
  bool bRet = false;

  for (; iAllocationIndex < linesList.Count - 1; ++iAllocationIndex )
  {
     int iTempIndex = iAllocationIndex;

     if (IndexesTobeRemoved.ContainsValue(iTempIndex)) continue;


     string line = linesList[iAllocationIndex];
     string strAllocationLine = line;
     string strPointerId = string.Empty;
     // Search For Allocation
     if (line.Contains("Allocation"))
     {
        int iIndex = line.IndexOf("Item :");
        strPointerId = line.Substring(iIndex + 6, line.Length - 1 - (iIndex + 5));
        for (int iDeAllocationIndex = iAllocationIndex; iDeAllocationIndex < linesList.Count - 1; ++iDeAllocationIndex)
        {

           if (IndexesTobeRemoved.ContainsValue(iDeAllocationIndex)) continue;

           string strDeallocationLine = linesList[iDeAllocationIndex];

           if (strDeallocationLine.Contains("Deallocation"))
           {
              if (strDeallocationLine.Contains(strPointerId))
              {
                 Console.WriteLine("Found {0} AllocIndex {1} DeAllocIndex {2}", strPointerId, iAllocationIndex+1, iDeAllocationIndex+1);

                 IndexesTobeRemoved.Add(iAllocationIndex, iAllocationIndex);
                 IndexesTobeRemoved.Add(iDeAllocationIndex, iDeAllocationIndex);

                 bRet = true;
                 break;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     if (bRet) break;
  }
  return bRet;
   }
}
```

**For about parsing *4 MB* file it took more than 6 hours and it's still continuing, Am i missing something here???**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please state what it means to parse the file and match allocations with deallocations. Right now I have to guess what your goal really is and that's not helping anyone. My initial reaction reading your code is that you have an O(N^2) situation with a loop-in-loop, it would be much better to simply read through the file once and grabbing things but since I don't really understand what the end result is supposed to be it's hard to formulate a good answer. In other words, in the final output file, what do you want of content and why?

Comment: Could it be that you want to read the original file, and keep only unmatched allocations and deallocations, meaning that if one allocation references number `233272976`, and another deallocates the same number, you want both of these removed? If so, can the same number occur more than once, say as allocate->deallocate->allocate?

Comment: Here's a super-stupid naive implementation of my assumption, please check if it does what you need done and how it behaves: https://gist.github.com/lassevk/bc39899282bed60f169f3de06502a82b - Note that a lot of optimizations can be done, including lazy-read of the input file, if additional assumptions or guarantees can be made. For instance, if every allocation comes before its matching deallocation, and we can at least keep the allocations in-memory, a single lazy pass can be made through the file instead of the read-into-memory implementation I made. 4MiB in 0.7 seconds with that approach.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Expected output is : read the allocation from top to bottom for example 233272976 is allocated and deallocated respectively in the file. **Delete this from the file**. The next one is 233273480 this , so leave this as it is in the file. I need this to find to out ids which are not de-allocated at the end of list , if any.

Comment: Test the code in the gist I linked to then and see if that works for you

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the code is not compiling which is shared in gisthub ,added comment to the gisthub link itself

Comment: Well, it runs on my end, best of luck then.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Well! It's Superb. It's working for me. Thanks a lot.

Algorithm is well written. Single Pass you finished everything , hence reduced time.

P.S. Your program is not working for me earlier , as it was not targeting to Rosyln compiler  (was using VS2012). The moment i switched it to VS2017 everything was smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [LasseVågsætherKarlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen) from his [gist link](https://gist.github.com/lassevk/bc39899282bed60f169f3de06502a82b) , re-written the program , which is much faster.

```
    public struct stReferenceMatch
{
    public bool bAllocated;
    public bool bDeAllocated;
}


class ReadFromFile1
{
    static string strFileName = @"C:\LogFile.Log";

    static void Main()
    {
        List<string>  linesList = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName).ToList();

        Dictionary<int, stReferenceMatch> IndexesTobeRemoved = new Dictionary<int, stReferenceMatch>();

        foreach (string line in linesList)
        {
            bool bAlloc, bDeAlloc;
            FindAllocDeAllocInString(line, out bAlloc, out bDeAlloc);

            if (bAlloc || bDeAlloc)
            {
                int iIndex = line.IndexOf("Item :");
                string strPointerId = line.Substring(iIndex + 6, line.Length - 1 - (iIndex + 5));
                int iPos = Convert.ToInt32(strPointerId);

                IndexesTobeRemoved.TryGetValue(iPos, out stReferenceMatch refMatch);
                if (bAlloc) refMatch.bAllocated = true;
                if (bDeAlloc) refMatch.bDeAllocated = true;
            }

        }
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output_new.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var line in linesList)
            {

                bool bAlloc, bDeAlloc;
                FindAllocDeAllocInString(line, out bAlloc, out bDeAlloc);
                if (bAlloc || bDeAlloc)
                {
                    int iIndex = line.IndexOf("Item :");
                    string strPointerId = line.Substring(iIndex + 6, line.Length - 1 - (iIndex + 5));
                    int iPos = Convert.ToInt32(strPointerId);


                    IndexesTobeRemoved.TryGetValue(iPos, out stReferenceMatch refMatch);

                    if (refMatch.bAllocated && refMatch.bDeAllocated)
                        continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }
        }


    }

    private static bool FindAllocDeAllocInString(string line, out bool bAlloc, out bool bDeAlloc)
    {
        // Search For Allocation & DeAllocation
        bAlloc = line.Contains("Allocation");
        bDeAlloc = line.Contains("Deallocation");

        return bAlloc || bDeAlloc;
    }
}
```